# jquery Issue with magento2.3 backend

Tags: magento2.3

[image]I am using the quick package of a magento2.3 version. Some of my jquery files like tinymce.js, plugin.js is not here in the directory that is generating issue in Magento admin. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Could you share the issue you are facing with screenshot

Comment: Please check the link for the screenshot http://prntscr.com/mverg0

Comment: Could not open this link.Is that url correct?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct URL. Please check

Comment: I couldn't open this.Some proxy settings is blocking this url

Comment: I have added the screenshot in main question.

Comment: Did u run commands like upgrade,content,cache ?

Comment: Yes i run upgrade, reindex, static-content and cache but this is same

Answer (score 0):

Try redeploying static contents specific for admin area:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml
```

Also, please make sure you are on a **developer mode**

Comment: I have done but still the issue is same. I have just analysed that plugin.js path is /admin/cms/page/edit/page_id/9/key/87a7decd5902541e7d38395c55228e39dabe949d1d1e5434c9ec2d4922e2aec0//plugins/help/plugin.js. This is the incorrect pahth. Any suggestion?

Comment: please set **Add Secret Key to URLs** to No in Store>configuration>Admin>Security and check again if plugin.js path is wrong

Comment: I am using quickstart package of a theme. They did not  provide the key. Is there any other to find the key?

Comment: can you try to use the default magento theme and check if issue still exist